# Label in table should cross another cell

Tags: tables

I want that the left column (the one with the 'caption' a=0) is as wide as the other columns but not by making the other colums wider! That means that the a= has to cross the cell on its left.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rccc}
&$a=0$&$1$&$2$\\\cline{2-4}
$c=0$&\\\cline{2-4}
$1$&\\\cline{2-4}
$2$&\\\cline{2-4}
\end{tabular}
\caption{caption}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So I want something like this (but the space between = and 0 should be the same as between a and = (and this should be the same as between c and =).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I `\llap` the `$a={}$` to the left of `$0$`.  The `{}` is necessary after the `=` to convince the `=` that an actual number will follow and to set the spacing appropriately.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rccc}
&\llap{$a={}$}$0$&$1$&$2$\\\cline{2-4}
$c=0$&\\\cline{2-4}
$1$&\\\cline{2-4}
$2$&\\\cline{2-4}
\end{tabular}
\caption{caption}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `\multicolumn{2}{r}{...}` setup.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}rccc@{}}
\multicolumn{2}{r}{$a=0$}& $1$ & $2$ \\\cline{2-4}
$c=0$&\\\cline{2-4}
$1$  &\\\cline{2-4}
$2$  &\\\cline{2-4}
\end{tabular}
\caption{caption}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```